# Reversing a user input string using methods

Tags: java, string, for-loop, while-loop, char

Here's a problem which takes a string input from the user and reverses the string.

For example:
input: "I love ice cream!"
output: "cream! ice love I"

Here's the source code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class stringProblems {

        static void reverse(char str[], int start, int end){
            char temp;
            while(start <= end){
                temp = str[start];
                str[start] = str[end];
                str[end] = temp;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        }
        static char[] reverseWords(char[] s){
            int start = 0;
            for(int end = 0; end < s.length; end++){
                if(s[end] == ' '){
                    reverse(s, start, end);
                    start = end + 1;
                }
            }
            reverse(s, start, s.length -1);
            reverse(s, 0, s.length-1);
            return s;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("enter the string to be reversed");
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = ss.nextLine();
        char[] p = reverseWords(s.toCharArray());
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

The doubt that I have is the for loop inside reverseWords method iterates until it finds an empty space. The input I gave was "I like ice cream!" So, at second iteration the condition in if(s[end] == ' ') statement becomes true and the reverse method is called. The while(start <= end) loop inside reverse method is executed as the value of start is 0 and end is 1 at first iteration. At the end the value of start is incremented to 1 and end is decremented to 0 because of start++; and end--; And in next iteration the condition is failed, it jumps to for(int end = 0; end <= s.length; end++) loop inside reverseWords method, now the value of end begins with 0 or 2 as it was 1 earlier when the " " space lies at 1 index in "I love ice cream!"?

Tip: understand the above source code to understand my question.

Comment: @WJS sure! but I want to know what happens specifically at this particular case ?

Comment: Is there an error, or are you requesting an explanation to how the code works?

Comment: @Reilas I want to understand how the code works during the above mentioned situation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly (the last paragraph was a bit long-winded), you're asking about the fact that there are `start` and `end` variables in two different methods that call each other, and how that affects those values.

The short answer is that they don't affect each other at all. Variables declared in one function are completely unrelated to variables of the same name in another function, and that includes function parameters.

The changes to `end` that were done in `reverse` are not visible to `reverseWords`. You can print `end` just before and after `reverse(s, start, end);` and you'll see the same value. If `end` was 1 before, it'll be 1 after.

Note that when you have containers and objects, changes done to values *inside* those containers and objects will be visible to everyone. That's because the variable itself is a reference, and if you hand this reference to another function they'll both point to the same underlying data structure.

---

As for your bug, the problem is that `reverse` swaps all the letters between `start` and `end` *inclusive*, that is, it swaps `s[start] <-> s[end]`, then `s[start+1] <-> s[end-1]`, etc. That's a problem because `reverseWords` calls it when `s[end] == ' '`, so the first letter will be swapped with the space, not the last letter.

To fix it, simply call `reverse` with the end moved back a little bit:

```
    static char[] reverseWords(char[] s){
        int start = 0;
        for(int end = 0; end < s.length; end++){
            if(s[end] == ' '){
                // Changed here to end-1.
                reverse(s, start, end-1);
                start = end + 1;
            }
        }
        reverse(s, start, s.length -1);
        reverse(s, 0, s.length-1);
        return s;
    }
```

```
enter the string to be reversed
I like ice cream!
cream! ice like I
```

Comment: hey @BoppreH after taking the input of type String, does the value is stored in the string constant pool or heap memory in runtime or compiling time? even when the String is passed as an argument to the reverseWords method and reverse method or it won't be stored in the memory ??

Comment: like in case it is stored in either of this memory at what time it happens whether runtime or compile time?

Comment: @sriram Because it's read with scanner, it's stored in the heap. The same string is shared between the functions, no copies are made. Try printing 's' at the end and you'll see it's also reversed.

Comment: so only the reference of String is been passed as argument not the actual value ?

Comment: @sriram in case of containers (like char[]) and objects (like String) the value is a reference to a memory location. Passing it as argument copies the address number, but not the contents pointed by the address. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-is-pass-by-value-and-not-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to explain.

It might be easier to visualize the flow of data by printing relevant values to the standard-out.

I've implemented a few outputs, from within the separate methods.

```java
static void reverse(char str[], int start, int end){
    char temp;
    while(start <= end){
        System.out.printf(" reverse,%n  start = %d, end = %d%n", start, end);
        temp = str[start];
        str[start] = str[end];
        str[end] = temp;
        System.out.printf("   temp assigned '%s'%n", str[start]);
        System.out.printf("   str[start] assigned '%s'%n", str[end]);
        System.out.printf("   str[end] assigned '%s'%n", temp);
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
static char[] reverseWords(char[] s){
    int start = 0;
    for(int end = 0; end < s.length; end++){
        System.out.printf("reverseWords, s[end] = '%s'%n", s[end]);
        if(s[end] == ' '){
            reverse(s, start, end);
            start = end + 1;
        }
    }
    reverse(s, start, s.length -1);
    reverse(s, 0, s.length-1);
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter the string to be reversed");
    Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = ss.nextLine();
    char[] p = reverseWords(s.toCharArray());
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Output

```
enter the string to be reversed
I like ice cream!
reverseWords, s[end] = 'I'
reverseWords, s[end] = ' '
 reverse,
  start = 0, end = 1
   temp assigned ' '
   str[start] assigned 'I'
   str[end] assigned 'I'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'l'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'i'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'k'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'e'
reverseWords, s[end] = ' '
 reverse,
  start = 2, end = 6
   temp assigned ' '
   str[start] assigned 'l'
   str[end] assigned 'l'
 reverse,
  start = 3, end = 5
   temp assigned 'e'
   str[start] assigned 'i'
   str[end] assigned 'i'
 reverse,
  start = 4, end = 4
   temp assigned 'k'
   str[start] assigned 'k'
   str[end] assigned 'k'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'i'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'c'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'e'
reverseWords, s[end] = ' '
 reverse,
  start = 7, end = 10
   temp assigned ' '
   str[start] assigned 'i'
   str[end] assigned 'i'
 reverse,
  start = 8, end = 9
   temp assigned 'e'
   str[start] assigned 'c'
   str[end] assigned 'c'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'c'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'r'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'e'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'a'
reverseWords, s[end] = 'm'
reverseWords, s[end] = '!'
 reverse,
  start = 11, end = 16
   temp assigned '!'
   str[start] assigned 'c'
   str[end] assigned 'c'
 reverse,
  start = 12, end = 15
   temp assigned 'm'
   str[start] assigned 'r'
   str[end] assigned 'r'
 reverse,
  start = 13, end = 14
   temp assigned 'a'
   str[start] assigned 'e'
   str[end] assigned 'e'
 reverse,
  start = 0, end = 16
   temp assigned 'c'
   str[start] assigned ' '
   str[end] assigned ' '
 reverse,
  start = 1, end = 15
   temp assigned 'r'
   str[start] assigned 'I'
   str[end] assigned 'I'
 reverse,
  start = 2, end = 14
   temp assigned 'e'
   str[start] assigned ' '
   str[end] assigned ' '
 reverse,
  start = 3, end = 13
   temp assigned 'a'
   str[start] assigned 'e'
   str[end] assigned 'e'
 reverse,
  start = 4, end = 12
   temp assigned 'm'
   str[start] assigned 'k'
   str[end] assigned 'k'
 reverse,
  start = 5, end = 11
   temp assigned '!'
   str[start] assigned 'i'
   str[end] assigned 'i'
 reverse,
  start = 6, end = 10
   temp assigned 'i'
   str[start] assigned 'l'
   str[end] assigned 'l'
 reverse,
  start = 7, end = 9
   temp assigned 'c'
   str[start] assigned ' '
   str[end] assigned ' '
 reverse,
  start = 8, end = 8
   temp assigned 'e'
   str[start] assigned 'e'
   str[end] assigned 'e'
cream!ice like I
```

Answer (score -1):

//change the method  of "reverseWords" as provided below

```
static char[] reverseWords(char[] s){
   int start = 0;
   reverse(s, start, s.length -1);
   return s;
    }
```

//Try the following To Reverse the Words Order

```
public static String reverseString(String input) {
    
    String[] array = input.split(" ");
    String output="";
    
    for(String str:array) {
        output = str+" "+output;
    } 
    return output;
}
```

Comment: That reverses the whole string, printing "!maerc eci ekil I". OP wants the *order* of the words reversed, as in "cream! ice love I".